# How to make data available from a Firefox profile folder to an extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to set a new Firefox profile's ([`firefox -profile "profile_path"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)) window title to include the profile's name using [`windows.update` and `titlePreface`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/update) programmatically. Browser extensions can be configured through options screens, but those involve a lot of clicking and cannot be automated.

Is there any way for me to write information in my Firefox profile folder, that I could then read from an extension? I want to write the profile's name to some file or sqlite database that the extension could read, if it is possible. I cycle through a lot of Firefox profiles and have custom my `user.js` and `userChrome.css`, but an extension's setup is more difficult and manual.

Another idea is to programmatically create the extension to already include the profile name, but each one would have to be signed making it too cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to write information in my Firefox profile
>   folder, that I could then read from an extension?

That is no longer possible in Firefox 57+

All settings access are only possible via the available API and they are not as extensive as the legacy Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, I will really have to dig into `nativeMessaging` then

Comment: Actually `nativeMessaging` is not an option either, how would I know which profile the message arrives from. No other choice than to switch to a release with `xpinstall.signatures.required` option and use profile specific unsigned extensions. ;_;

Comment: @Mr.RanDum As mentioned, extensions do not have file access so they cant get those info unless an API is created by Mozilla.